# Do i need a vpc created before i pass on the value to the internet gateway in Terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I am learning Terraform using modules. I have created two modules for vpc and internet gateway. Please find the code below

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "internet_gateway" {
  source = "./modules/internet_gateway"
}
```

```
resource "aws_vpc" "some_custom_vpc" {
  cidr_block = "10.0.0.0/16"

  tags = {
    Name = "Some Custom VPC"
  }
}

output "vpc_id" {
  value = aws_vpc.some_custom_vpc.id
}
```

```
resource "aws_internet_gateway" "some_ig" {
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "Some Internet Gateway"
  }
}
```

However, when I am running `terraform init` and `terraform plan`, I am getting below error

```
│ Error: Reference to undeclared module
│ 
│   on .terraform/modules/internet_gateway/main.tf line 2, in resource "aws_internet_gateway" "some_ig":
│    2:   vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
│ 
│ No module call named "vpc" is declared in module.internet_gateway.
```

Can anyone please help me with what can be the reason for this error?
Do I need to create VPC alone first and then reference it to the internet gateway or is there any other solution?

Please consider that I am beginner so I might have missed techinacl details, if required please let me know I'll add it up.

Thanks in advance.

I have tried looking online for help but couldn't avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass `vpc_id` as an argument to your `module "internet_gateway"`. For example:

```
provider "aws" {
  profile = "default"
  region  = "us-east-1"
}

module "vpc" {
  source = "./modules/vpc"
}

module "internet_gateway" {
  source = "./modules/internet_gateway"
  vpc_id = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

This requires declaration of `vpc_id` variable in `"./modules/internet_gateway"`, and subsequent use of the variable in the module:

```
variable "vpc_id" {}

resource "aws_internet_gateway" "some_ig" {
  vpc_id = var.vpc_id

  tags = {
    Name = "Some Internet Gateway"
  }
}
```